# Rails: using inverse_of on has_many relation does not reduce queries to databse

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Ruby on Rails project, the Course model is like this:

```
    class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :teams, inverse_of: :course, dependent: :destroy
```

and the Team model is like this:

```
    class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :course
```

Inverse_of should help me prevent a query into the database when I do the following if statement

```
    if(tm.course == current_course) #tm is a team and current_course is a course
      return tm
```

I check the console output and see that the if statement still invokes this:

```
    CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `courses`.* FROM `courses` WHERE `courses`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
```

Any thoughts and advices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's perfectly fine. That query is not hitting the database again. That `CACHE (0.0ms)` is from the Rails cache, usually in-memory unless you change it in the app configuration.

EDIT

Actually, if you want to frequently access the association object you might also want to add `include`.

`has_many :teams, -> { includes :course }, inverse_of: :course, dependent: :destroy`

That should force Rails to load both records in a single database access and keep them both in the cache.

ANOTHER EDIT

If you want to avoid a second transaction you can do something like `tm = Team.includes(:course).find params[:id]`. That way when the if happens the query won't need a new transaction.
Instead you will see the two SELECTs one after the other when you call `find`. I think that's the best it can get.

Something important about `inverse_of` is that its purpose is for `tm.course.team` to not trigger a second select over `Team` and instead notice that `.team` refers to `tm` and only make two selects instead of three.

YET ANOTHER EDIT

Please try this in `rails console`.

`Team.first.course.team` with `inverse_of` on, then change it, reload the console and run it again. You will see what I mean.

FINAL (HOPEFULLY) EDIT

I'll try to explain [this](https://viget.com/extend/exploring-the-inverse-of-option-on-rails-model-associations) in detail...

`prison   = Prison.create(name: 'Bad House')`

This will cause a SELECT to be made against the database for the table `Prison`.

`criminal = prison.criminals.create(name: 'Krazy 8')`
This will cause an INSERT in the table `Criminal` and then a SELECT to retrieve it and assign it into the variable `criminal`.

If I had `inverse_of: :course` it would mean that accessing `criminal.prison` *won't* result in another query since `criminal` will "remember" that he has generated through `prison` there it will return the variable `prison` instead of querying again the db.

In your case... let's say you are creating the `tm` like this:

`tm = Team.find param[:id]`

This will cause an access to the database no matter what you do.

Then `tm.course == current_course` will need a second SELECT, this time against `Course` to find the course since you haven't used `Course` so far.

Then, lets assume you do this:

`course = tm.course`

and then `copy_of_team = course.team`. This is where you will see the effect of `inverse_of`.

If you want to get rid of that second select you MUST use `tm = Team.includes(:course).find param[:id]`. This will of course still need one select to retrieve the course information but it will happen in the same database transaction so it is a little better than not having it.

Comment: But I am still curious why this doesn't work. I am trying to reduce the queries to database for optimization purposes.

Comment: I updated my answer. But note that you are reducing them. That `CACHE (0.0ms) SELECT...` is not coming from your database.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I try turning the inverse_of off and it still has no effect on the result. I guess inverse_of has no effect on the results.

Comment: I've updated my answer one more time, I think that is what you are looking for. Let me know

Comment: Uh according to this link: https://viget.com/extend/exploring-the-inverse-of-option-on-rails-model-associations   the inverse_of should eliminate the extra query into Course because it recognizes the course the team belongs to.

Comment: Not really. In that particular case it is true because in `criminal.prison`, `criminal` is `prison.criminals.create(name: 'Krazy 8')`. Then you would be accessing `Prison` then `Criminal` and then `Prison` again. If instead criminal where queried directly from the `Criminal` model instead of through the first `Prison` association so would see the same result you are seeing with your models.

Comment: I see what u mean. Thx!